# received sms and show in textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, sms

I write program for sending and receiving sms in android and display received content sms in text view. I want to received sms in program, not in inbox messege!!!
I know must use from textview.settext("smsContentEtc") but I cant use and implements it.
I put total code. sms.java for send sms and SmsReceiver.java for received sms.
please help me.

sms.java

```
public class SMS extends Activity {

        Button btnSendSMS;
        EditText txtPhoneNo;
        EditText txtMessage;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);          
            btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
            txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
            txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);         
            btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {                
                    String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                    String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
                    if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                        sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });        
        } 
        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {        
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            //---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;                        
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));             
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
        }
}
```

SmsReceiver .java

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private TextView txtshow;
         @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {
                //---get the SMS message passed in---
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                String str = "";            
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                    //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 

                    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                         
                        str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                        str += " :";
                        str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                        str += "\n";  

                    }
                    //---display the new SMS message---
                   //Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    txtshow.setText("smsContentEtc");                  
                }                         
            }
        }
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Enter the phone number of recipient"
        />     

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:text="Message"
        />     

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send SMS"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_Show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="@bool/r"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SMS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter > 
                <action android:name=
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use setText or any other method of view's like that

> txtshow.setText("smsContentEtc");

In order to modify your text view, first you should use R.findViewById and initialize your view, but since your class doesn't extends from Activity you can't use it. Instead I suggest you to use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Also if you don't want sms in inbox, you can use [AbortBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29)

Comment: I dont know AbortBroadcast and Shared Preferences what is!!!! I should very change my program? Please help me for where I change code!!

Comment: @inankupeli: can you give us a sample on how to use Shared Preferences?